# Problems installing ReSharper: JetBrains Installer.ReSharper.Bootstrap could not run

Tags: resharper

I have problems installing ReSharper.
Every time I start the installer, the following error occurs:
"JetBrains Installer.ReSharper.Bootstrap could not run.

Could not Ioad the JetLauncher Managed Core into the

application domain. Could not Ioad the assembly from

resource #777. The File or Assembly "208936 bytes Ioaded

from mscorlib, Version-4.0.0.0, Culture-neutral,

PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" or a dependency

could not be found. Exception from HRESULT:

OxD0000003"

I am using VS 2022. My System and VS is up to date.

Things i have already tried are:

- updating Anything
- Windows
- VS 2022
- .NET CORE (version 6.0.401)
- different Installation Methodes
- web Installer
- offline Installer

Has anyone the same problem or can someone help me?
Thank you

Comment: You should ask on the [ReSharper support forum](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366389-ReSharper-Community).

Answer (score 1):

I did ask the Resharper community and it turns out, that even if I have Administrator rights on my machine, a policy deployed by my Company blocks the installation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).